# Grouping figures in \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Is it possible to group together several figures in the List of Figures. For example a time step sequence where there are 4 or 5 different figures would only have one entry.

Comment: Do you have (or need) separate captions for each of the "time steps"? If not, then you can group them all in a single `figure` environment with only a single caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add lines to the `listoffigures` file (`\jobaname.lof`) using the command

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{Time step sequence}
```

If you use the `caption` package, then you can typeset your captions using

```
\caption[]{first}%
```

which will put an empty entry in the `lof`. This produces

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{Time step sequence}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\rule{20pt}{30pt}
\caption[]{first}%
\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\rule{20pt}{30pt}
\caption{second}%
\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Or perhaps you want something like '1-2: Time step sequences'? In which case, you can use

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\ref{fig:first}|\ref{fig:second} Time step sequences }
```

which produces

[image]