# Multiple references to subfigures in figure caption

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, subfloats

For reasons, I need a specific numbering for my subfigures in a figure environment. I want the caption of the figure environment to refer to the subfigures as follows: Figures 1-4. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gridsize}{0.45}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure}
\subfloat[Subfigure (1)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\subfloat[Subfigure (2a)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:subfig2a}
}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{1}
\subfloat[Subfigure (2b)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:subfig2b}
}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}
\subfloat[Subfigure (2c)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:subfig2c}
}\\
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure}
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\subfloat[Subfigure (3)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}
\setcounter{figure}{3}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\subfloat[Subfigure (4a)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:subfig4a}
}
\setcounter{figure}{3}
\setcounter{subfigure}{1}
\subfloat[Subfigure (4b)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:subfig4b}
}
\setcounter{figure}{3}
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}
\subfloat[Subfigure (4c)]{
    \includegraphics[width=\gridsize\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:subfig4c}
}
\label{fig:figure}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your fragment to a compilable example!

Comment: My example is now compilable, my problem is to have Figures 1-4 in the numbering of the main caption instead of Figure 4 as it is right now. I would also like to have 1-4 where I refer to the main figure environment label.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide actual subfigure captions, I tried to adapt.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:subfig2}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \label{fig:subfig3}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \label{fig:subfig4}
    \end{minipage}
    Main Caption% will not increment figure counter nor appear in list of figures
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. By removing the \caption{}, I can manually define the title of the main caption, which is a sort of a solution. But I would still be interested in a dynamic solution to my problem.

Comment: If you want to add something to the list of figures, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43869/grouping-figures-in-listoffigures